# Find all the asymptotes of the equation

Tags: asymptotics

> Find the alll asymptotes of the equation
> $$x^3-x^2y-xy^2+y^3+2x^2-4y^2+2xy+x+y+1=0.$$

Here's what i tried:

Equation for oblique asymptotes-
\begin{align}
\varphi_3(m)&=1-m-m^2+m^3\\
\varphi_2(m)&=2-4m^2+2m\\
\varphi_1(m)&=1+m\\
\varphi_0(m)&=1
\end{align}

$$\varphi_3(m)= m=1,1,-1.$$

for $m=-1$ it's $c\varphi_3(m)+\varphi_2(m)=0$

on solving the above it's coming $4=0$.

I don't know where I did wrong.

Comment: Hello, I have made an edit to fix the latex, please check if I made any mistake.

Comment: Hey you changed the coefficient of x^3 from 1 to 4 so that actually changes the whole question!!

Comment: I have not looked as asymptotics in quite some time. Does the double root at $1$ change the process? I do not recall.

Comment: Suppose the coefficient of x^ 3 is 4. Then φ3(m)=4-m-m^2+m^3 but if it's 1 then φ3(m)=1-m-m^2+m^3 and as far as i know we should get different values of m.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales nvm i got the mistake , actually it is  cφ3(m)'+φ2(m)=0 , i was not  differentiating the φ3(m) before multiplying it with c

Comment: $\varphi_3 = m$ should have been $\varphi_3 = 0$. The curve contains two points at infinity, $(1, 1, 0)$ and $(1, -1, 0)$. If we take $x = 1$, the leading terms in the Taylor expansion around $(y, z) = (-1, 0)$ are $4(y + 1) - 4 z$. Homogenizing back gives an asymptote $y + x = z$. The leading terms in the Taylor expansion around $(y, z) = (1, 0)$ are
$$2 (y - 1)^2 - 6 (y - 1) z + 2 z^2 =
2 (y - 1 - k_1 z) (y - 1 - k_2 z),$$
which gives two more asymptotes $y - x = k_{1, 2} z$.